# how to use return value of soap web service in soap client

Tags: web-services, soap, jakarta-ee, webservice-client, soap-client

I have an soap web service that has a method like

```
public WsResult doMyJob(String s, Information info);
```

when I generate a client out of the wsdl, in the client code my webservice's method becomes something like:

```
public Object doMyJob(String s, Object arg0);
```

The problem is that I want client to be able to implement/see my custom classes(WsResult and Information) without explicitly defining them in his code.

Is that even possible and if so how?

Thanks

edit:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions name="SendSms" targetNamespace="http://webservice.aaa.bbb.com/" xmlns:ns1="http://webservice.aaa.bbb.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://webservice.aaa.bbb.com/" xmlns="http://webservice.aaa.bbb.com/" xmlns:tns="http://impl.webservice.aaa.bbb.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="registerScheduledSms" type="registerScheduledSms" />
<xsd:complexType name="registerScheduledSms">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="arg1" /> **HERE THERE SHOULD BE xsd definition for my custom class**
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="arg2" /> **and here**
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="arg3" type="xsd:dateTime" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="registerScheduledSmsResponse" type="registerScheduledSmsResponse" />
<xsd:complexType name="registerScheduledSmsResponse">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="return" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="registerScheduledSmsResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="ns1:registerScheduledSmsResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="registerScheduledSms">
    <wsdl:part element="ns1:registerScheduledSms" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="SendSms">
    <wsdl:operation name="registerScheduledSms">
      <wsdl:input message="ns1:registerScheduledSms" name="registerScheduledSms">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="ns1:registerScheduledSmsResponse" name="registerScheduledSmsResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

my service code

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.bbb.aaa.webservice.SendSms")
public class SendSmsImpl implements SendSms {

    private DbService dbService;

    @Override
    public WsResult registerScheduledSms(String applicationId,
            ServiceAccount serviceAccount, Sms sms, Date scheduledDate) {


        return dbService.addNewScheduledSms(applicationId, serviceAccount, sms, scheduledDate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's perfectly possible. Your **soap client** should generate all classes defined in the schema types on your **WSDL**. You are probable missing something on client generation.

It would help if you specify **what** are you using for client generation (AXIS, .NET, JAX-WS) and confirm that your **WSDL** contains schema definitions for `WsResult` and `Information` types.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, I am using JAX-WS (wsdl2java binary) to generate client out of wsdl. But in my wsdl file there is nothing about my custom classes. I know that is the problem. how can I make my server generate wsdl with my custom class' definitions?

Comment: What Application Server are you using? Tomcat, JBoss, Websphere, Oracle's, BEA Weblogic? As your problem is probably on the server side right now, it would help if you post the code for your server, and your WSDL currently being generated.

Comment: @Pablo Santa Cruz : I am working on tomcat. I am adding the files right now to the my original answer

Comment: Your WSDL seems too short. Are your WsResult and ServiceAccount classes public?

Comment: yes they are all public and I use tomcat6. actually my xml imports another xml which I have added to the question now